# Make =IMPORTRANGE interactive/not to update?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with information and another where I import the data, but I want to be able to change the data in the imported sheet.

How is this possible? Once the data is published it doesn't need to update again if I change in the main sheet

SO:

I have one big sheet with lots of tabs that I cannot share

One of the tabs I want to share with colleagues

The colleagues should be able to update the sheet (doesn't need to update the "main" sheet again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention

> I have a sheet with information and another where I import the data, but I want to be able to change the data in the imported sheet.
>
> ... One of the tabs I want to share with colleagues
>
> ... The colleagues should be able to update the sheet

**Please follow these steps**

1. Link the sheet AND import the initial values.
2. Go to the tab with the imported values you want to *"freeze"* and select the whole range with values
3. Right click and select `Copy`
4. Go to menu `Edit`-> `Paste special`-> `Paste values only`
5. Enjoy the *"frozen"* tab.

Comment: Glad I could help and thank you for accepting.